# When to explicitly save with CoreData in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

I'm currently working on a simple CoreData app for iPad and I'm not exactly sure when I have to explicitly save.  I know that there is auto-save; however, I feel that I need to explicitly save in order to make sure my program doesn't crash.  Here's a brief overview of the program:

~ It's a form program that presents the user with a set of text fields and segmented controls to fill out.  (Think a person filling out a survey, or answering questions about their name, age...etc).

~ Any number of these fields can be filled out. None of them are mandatory.

~ A user can save and load their form at any time and they can have multiple different forms saved at once.  They can delete their saved documents

~ I'm currently storing this data using core data where one entity object represents a form.  This entity object contains a list of all of the fields which the user has completed and their responses to each field.

~ I also have an NSManagedObject subclass of  this entity object. Thus every time a field is filled out I do something such as `currentForm.name = textfield.text`.

Ok, so my question is, when do I have to explicitly save? If I write code such as `currentForm.name = textfield.text` does core data perform an immediate save or do I have to explicitly tell it to do so (assuming that I don't want to wait for the auto-save)? Are there any other times when I might have to save? Do I have to save after I delete a stored document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you save

```
NSError *error;

    if (![[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] save:&error]) 
{
        NSLog(@"there was an error in Save:%@",error);
    }
```

I would save "early and often" or at least on Notifications for didEnterBackground

Comment: So if I write the following line: `currentForm.name = textfield.text` then you would suggest I explicitly save?

Comment: Yeah, creating a inserting a new object for Entity is trivial for core data, especially if that object is a string. it won't slow down anything you're doing.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend saving after every entry from the user, your context is kind of like a transaction. You can rollback changes when a user cancels or you can commit changes when a user says they are done making changes.

Answer (score 4):

So, there is no "auto-save", it just so happens that the Core Data template Apple has setup includes a save routine when the application is closed which is more of a fail safe to make sure your user does not lose any data.

You should be calling save whenever your user explicitly saves something or when you deem necessary.

I would call save after the user has finished filling the form.

> currentNotification.name = textfield.text does core data perform an immediate save or do I have to explicitly tell it to do so (assuming that I don't want to wait for the auto-save)?

No, the changes will be made in your NSManagedObjectContext, but until save is explicitly called on that context the data will not be persisted to your persistence store.

Answer (score 2):

I have not heard of Core Data autosaving? You should call save on your NSManagedObjectContext whenever you want to persist your data. Here is another similar question to your: [Auto-save with Cocoa and Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1500327/294661)