# SwitfUI - how to update the view after certain action ,or time , or when the coreData has any changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, boolean

I have a list of quotes and you can save your favorites to CoreData persistent store , or delete them.

But when you delete them from  the favorites list  , the quotes list don't update fast to show the Boolean value (isFavorited) , it's a lot of code to add here but all i want is for quotes view to update after certain time , or action.

Comment: Perhaps use local notifications, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101845/coredata-get-notified-when-nsmanagedobject-is-changed-without-keeping-reference

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing this data in your SwiftUI View?

You can power a SwiftUI view from a fetch request directly.

Example:

```
struct FavoriteQuotesView: View {
  @FetchRequest(entity: Quote.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isFavorited == true")) var quotes: FetchedResults<Quote>

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(quotes) { quote in 
        Text(quote.text)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As data is updated that affects that query, it will update your SwiftUI view.