# Core Data and Notification Identifier SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create a notification using information from a user-created object in CoreData. However, I can't find a good property of the CoreData object to set as an identifier for the notification. I tried using the 'name' property of the object but there might be other objects with the same input so that is not a very safe approach.

How can I set a unique identifier for each notification that I can read from an object in CoreData?

My code is still too messy to post here but I can clear it up if you want.

Below is the latest approach I tried but this seems to be not working. It behaves as if ID is not a unique property.

```
         let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Reminder"
        content.body = name
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        let identifier = "\(Reminder.ID.self)"
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var reminderDate = DateComponents()
        reminderDate = calendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute], from: remdate)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: reminderDate, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
```

Comment: Can you please explain or give me an example? I'm new to swift UI.

Comment: Apologies, I meant UUID not UDID. You can have a attribute ID in core data that will save each user with unique ID, like PK. As UUID stands for  universally unique identifier.

Comment: Sounds nice! Should I add another attribute to the entity? Or is it already there? 
Also, how can I pass it as a string for notification identifier?

Comment: You can save UUID directly as string in data model. And add values by calling UUID().uuidString.If you already have a ID attribute you can modify it, if it’s not a big change.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do here but regarding an unique Id you should know that every object from a NSManagedObject subclass has a unique id, [objectID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506848-objectid) and also note that Core Data also emits notifications when the NSManagedObjectContext changes. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44101845/coredata-get-notified-when-nsmanagedobject-is-changed-without-keeping-reference) can be helpful

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks for your answers and patience. UUID is definetly my answer but I have this problem right now. This may sound stupid but after adding an UUID attribute, I can't seem to generate a unique UUID for each object so I fail at saving the object. Don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Let me try to explain myself. I have an entity and I save objects of the entity in CoreData. When users create an object, I want to create a local notification with it. Thus, I need to have a common property between the object and local notification so I can edit/delete local notification with the object later. Notification identifier seems like a good place to start with but I have no idea how to connect the object and notification.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for all the confusion caused! I was able to set the entity's UUID to a local notification identifier! Thanks, @TusharSharma! You have been a great help!

Comment: @KalayciMusa great.